# How to simulate uploading file via Ant Design's Upload using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-testing-library

I am using Ant Design's Upload component.

```
 <Upload 
     accept=".xlsx" 
     onChange={onImport}
  >
     <Button>Upload</Button>
 </Upload>
```

I have attempted to simulate the change using fireEvent.change which does nothing:

```
const inputEl = screen.getByText('Import');
const file = new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.xlsx');
fireEvent.change(inputEl, { target: { files: [file] } });
```

I also tried to use fireEvent.drop. I tried setting both the dataTransfer and files properties.

```
Object.defineProperty(inputEl, 'dataTransfer', {
    value: {
        files: [file]
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(inputEl, 'files', {
    value: [file]
});
fireEvent.drop(inputEl);
```

This triggers the upload, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
  at AjaxUploader._this.onFileDrop (node_modules/rc-upload/lib/AjaxUploader.js:108:63)
```

How can I test Ant Design's Upload?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I handled it. Since `input` is hidden and you can not query it with RTL I just queried the input using `document` like this:

```
async simulateFileUpload() {
  const file = new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.png', { type: 'image/png' });
  const hiddenFileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as Element;

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.change(hiddenFileInput, { target: { files: [file] } });
  });
}
```

Not the prettiest thing to do, but it is the only way to test upload functionality.
I wrapped `fireEvent` in `await act()` but that is only because upload triggers some state changes in my application, you can just use throw it away of course

Answer (score 1):

You can use user-event; is a companion library for Testing Library that provides more advanced simulation of browser interactions than the built-in fireEvent method.

Installation:

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event
```

Usage:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

test('upload file', () => {
   const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' })

    render(
        <div>
           <label htmlFor="file-uploader">Upload file:</label>
           <input id="file-uploader" type="file" />
        </div>
    )
    const input = screen.getByLabelText(/upload file/i)
    userEvent.upload(input, file)

    expect(input.files[0]).toStrictEqual(file)
    expect(input.files.item(0)).toStrictEqual(file)
    expect(input.files).toHaveLength(1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination between the two answers, plus the handling of the requests is what has worked for me. In this example you don't provide a URL to do the POST request, but the Dragger component of Ant Design has this option available.
I just want to share my solution for this question + an extra issue I found while using the `action` property, just to save you time.

To test the Dragger I did this:

```
test("Dragger functionality", async () => {
  const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
  const file = new File(["{test: 1}"], "test.json", {type: 'application/json'})
  const input = screen.getByTestId("uploader"); 
  // I added the data-testid property to the Dragger element, with the value "uploader"
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.change(input, {target: {files: [file]}});
  });
  await flushPromises();
});
```

The `userEvent.upload` method never worked for me. I've been using the `userEvent` for all the other tests but I couldn't make it work in this case.

---

**Extra:** If you are using the Dragger as I was

```
<Dragger multiple={true} accept={".json"} onChange={onChange} action={"/test"} data-testid={"uploader"}>
```

with the `onChange` and `action` properties, you will probably not get the `onChange` called.
To make it work, you have to handle the POST request that is made, in this case to the `/test`. So, the complete test would be:

```
import { act, fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { rest } from "msw";
import React from "react";
import { Upload } from "antd";
const { Dragger } = Upload;

const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
  
const server = setupServer(rest.post("/test", (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(ctx.json({response: "200 OK"}));
}));

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

test("Dragger functionality", async () => {
  const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
  
  render (
    <Dragger multiple={true} accept={".json"} onChange={onChangeMock} action={"/test"} data-testid={"uploader"}>
      <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
        <InboxOutlined />
      </p>
      <p className="ant-upload-text">{"description"}</p>
      <p className="ant-upload-hint">{"hint"}</p>
    </Dragger>
  );
  
  const file = new File(["{test: 1}"], "test.json", {type: 'application/json'})
  const input = screen.getByTestId("uploader"); 
  // I added the data-testid property to the Dragger element, with the value "uploader"
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.change(input, {target: {files: [file]}});
  });
  await flushPromises();
  expect(onChangeMock).toBeCalled();
});
```

Hopefully this is useful for someone.